# Redirect IP adress to default domain name

Tags: apache-2.2, domain-name-system

I'm running VPS with multiple domains.

When I type IP of my sever into browser, I want visitors to be redirected to specified domain name.

It is possible? Now it shows Default Debain Apache2 page.

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Edit your default site with

```
sudo nano /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000default.conf
```

And add this

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName www.domain1.com
Redirect / http://www.domain2.com
</VirtualHost>
```

More info here: [How To Create Temporary and Permanent Redirects with Apache and Nginx](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-temporary-and-permanent-redirects-with-apache-and-nginx)

Comment: Please explain what this code is doing.

Comment: The surrounding statement virtual host defines a server instance, the numer in the head defines the port it listens on. 80 is the standard http port. The servername directive defines what requested domain names it listes on. That means if you set it differently then the domain name it accually is on, it wont respond. As you want to redirect from an ip, you can just leave it away. The second statement "redirect" defines a redirect response. "/" defines that all requests will be redirected and the second argument behind "redirect" will be the redirect target, so your domain

Comment: (Besides: There is a typo in your post `Sudo [...]`. Maybe you could fix this as well, to prevent inexperienced users from running into `command not found`.)